# How to export data from table as CSV from Greenplum database to AWS s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, greenplum

I have data in a table

```
select * from my_table
```

It contains `10k` observations.How do I export data in the table as CSV to `s3` bucket .
(I dont want to export the data to my local machine and then push to `s3`).

Comment: Suspect this is massive overkill but DMS can probably do this (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.S3.html). Any reason you don't want to write a simple client-side (or perhaps Lambda function) to do this?

Comment: Are you using Greenplum or Postgres?

Answer (score 2):

Please, please, please STOP labeling your questions with both PostgreSQL and Greenplum.  The answer to your question is very different if you are using Greenplum versus PostgreSQL.   I can't stress this enough.

If you are using Greenplum, you should the S3 protocol in External Tables to read and write data to S3.

So your table:

```
select * from my_table;
```

And your external table:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ext_my_table (LIKE my_table) 
LOCATION ('s3://s3_endpoint/bucket_name')
FORMAT 'TEXT' (DELIMITER '|' NULL AS '' ESCAPE AS E'\\');
```

And then writing to your s3 bucket:

```
INSERT INTO ext_my_table SELECT * FROM my_table;
```

You will need to do some configuration on your Greenplum cluster so that you have an s3 configuration file too.  This goes in every segment directory too.

```
gpseg_data_dir/gpseg-prefixN/s3/s3.conf
```

Example of the file contents:

```
[default]
secret = "secret"
accessid = "user access id"
threadnum = 3
chunksize = 67108864
```

More information on S3 can be found here: http://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/5100/admin_guide/external/g-s3-protocol.html#amazon-emr__s3_config_file

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest to first load data into your master node using WINSCP or File transfer.
Then move this file from your master node to S3 storage.

Because, moving data from Master node to S3 storage utilises Amazon's bandwidth and it will be much faster than our local connection bandwidth used to transfer file from local machine to S3.